# XML Namespace in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

i need to get few value such as

1. w:val="FFFF00"
2. w:val="28"
3. Declaration word

from the xml file please help me with code

I have Tried this code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('document.xml')
# root = tree.getroot()
ns={'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}

for char in tree.findall('w:color',ns):
        print(' |-->', char.text)
```

please help me with the code how do i use xml namespaces in python to get value
this is XML Code:-

```
<w:tc>
    <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="1502" w:type="dxa"/>
    </w:tcPr>
    <w:p w:rsidP="00065164" w:rsidRDefault="006F598E" w:rsidRPr="009D1FCD" w:rsidR="006F598E">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:autoSpaceDE w:val="0"/>
            <w:autoSpaceDN w:val="0"/>
            <w:adjustRightInd w:val="0"/>
            <w:jc w:val="center"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
                <w:b/>
                <w:color w:val="FFFF00"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="009D1FCD">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
                <w:b/>
                <w:color w:val="FFFF00"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>YEAR</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:tc>

<w:p w:rsidP="00443849" w:rsidRDefault="00104308" w:rsidRPr="00383A2A" w:rsidR="00104308">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="NoSpacing"/>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
            <w:b/>
            <w:sz w:val="28"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00383A2A">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
            <w:b/>
            <w:sz w:val="28"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="28"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Declaration:</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Comment: `<w:color>` is not a child element of the root, so you need to provide the path, e.g. `tree.findall('.//w:color', ns)` to find `w:color` anywhere in the document.

Comment: ok so is it possible to find w:color directly

Comment: Use the path I described above. Note: There is no `text` for `ws:color`, perhaps you meant to get the `attrib`s.

Comment: Without adding root element you can extract any attribute value

Comment: @AChampion i tried that but an its worked

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('resume.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
ns={'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}

for char in root.findall('.//w:color',ns):
        print(char.attrib)

Answer (score 0):

Data can also be extract using `xml.dom` module.
here is the code:

```
from xml.dom import expatbuilder
document = expatbuilder.parse("sample.xml", False)
node = document.getElementsByTagName('w:p')
for i in node:
    color_list =  i.getElementsByTagName('w:color')
    wvalue_data =  [d.getAttribute('w:val') for d in color_list ]
    if  wvalue_data:
        print "color w:val :" , wvalue_data
    desc_list = i.getElementsByTagName('w:t')
   print "desc   :" ,[node.firstChild.data for node in desc_list]
    wsz_data = i.getElementsByTagName('w:sz')
    value_data = [data.getAttribute('w:val') for data in wsz_data ]
    if value_data:
        print "w:sz_value :" , value_data
```

Output will be as follows:

```
color w:val : [u'FFFF00', u'FFFF00']
desc   : [u'YEAR']
desc   : [u'Declaration:']
w:sz_value : [u'28', u'28']
```

Hope it is useful.